# Making fields reportable in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-reports

I need to collect certain data from TFS that is not configured as reportable by the TFS administrators using the TFS SQL DB. For example, if I need to query for the dates on which a set of work items was closed, I can do so within TFS, but when I write a SQL query (SELECT microsoft_vsts_common_closeddate FROM table WHERE ), the value for the closed date in every one of the items is NULL (the administrator has confirmed that this data is not provided to the TFS DB, only through queries written in TFS).

Because it's a shared server, hosting multiple TFS projects, they cannot make these fields reportable. Can I capture this data by creating custom fields, with all of the field configurations being the same as the default field except for the reportable value, which I would set to something other than NONE?

Comment: Are you querying the warehouse, or the cube? Also, not the leaving the default work item closed date to dimension seems really, really strange to me. Is the reporting attribute set to "none", or is it just not set?

Comment: The warehouse - but that raises a potential solution. I should see if I can get read access to the cube. That might solve a lot of my problems. As for the setting of the closed date field, Reporting is actually set to Dimension in the WIT file, and when I try to change it I get the error message that I need to change it in the DB (for which, of course, I need to be a PCA). So I'm thinking that the issue is with the fact that I am querying the warehouse. I will see if I can get read access to the cube.

Comment: Yeah, if it is set to dimension, querying the cube should get you what you need.

Comment: aclear, thanks. I was just informed by the service team that if it's not available in the databases to which I have access, that is because it's not retained in the cube. Based on that, and previous experience with that team, it's immaterial as to whether that's true or not, I'm not going to make any progress with them. It looks like what other teams are doing is actually creating project specific DBs, and then capturing the data from custom fields in those.

Comment: Someone on the support team found the resolution. The field is reportable, it just wasn't being captured in the actual work item forms or their corresponding workflows. Once I figure out how to edit workflows, I should be all set.

Comment: @Chris you can self-answer if you feel it is worth to capture that knowledge. I'm visiting this post due to [a re-tag action](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399176/578411)

Comment: @rene, sorry. This post is from so long ago, I don't remember the detail of what I did to resolve the issue. I do remember that I was able to resolve it, and it did involve editing our workflows in TFS to capture the closed date, and I believe it was pretty straightforward to search online and figure out how to do that.